# .jar file doesnt open when double clicking and also not with command prompt

Tags: java, jar

since yesterday i am not able to acces any .jar file on my laptop , i've tried re-installing java jre
and also tried the enviroment JAVA_HOME but that also does not work.

any tips/solutions for me ?

Comment: What do you mean by *not able to access any .jar file*? Which error message do you get? Is this opened by another application?

Comment: what command are you using? and what do u get when you run it?

Comment: If a jar is not runnable you cannot just double-click it to run it.

Comment: @luiggi mendoza , i dont get a error message at all, it just does not open

Comment: @Yazan Java -jar client.jar

Comment: @DanielOlszewski the .jar was fully functional yesterday, but when i started my laptop today i could not open any .jar file

Comment: There must be an error message. Try executing it with `java jar yourJar.jar`. Don't trust in double-click usage.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Error : Could not find main class jar

Comment: Open your Jar with a zip file manager like WinRar (on Windows). Check if the MANIFEST.MF file contains the main class, otherwise you should execute the jar using `java -cp yourJar.jar location.of.MainClass`

Answer (score 0):

have you made an GUI?

without your own GUI you will not be able to open it in double click and you will have to run it through cmd.

learn about JFrame/AWT to do that.

to run the jar from the cmd if you font have GUI and don't want one. write that in cmd:

```
java -jar JarName.jar
```